# How to create a responsive image with a button/link responding with width in the middle of image

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website and I want to have a link or a button in the middle of this image
[PC Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLt7H.jpgstrong)
the link/button needs to be in the center of the PC screen and say "Start Learning" when the link/button is clicked it will link to another page. I have tried creating this on my own and am trying to make the website responsive but when I am at 100% browser width the link is perfectly centered and when i minimize the browser the PC Image stays at 100% width which is good and responsive but the "Start Learning" link wont stay centered on the image and minimize with it, the link just jumps around the page.

Comment: Can you please post your attempted code or link a JSFiddle?

Comment: <header>
<div class="banner-inner">
<img src="img/Website PC.png" style="max-width:100%;">
<div class="centered"><a href="courses.html">Start Learning</a></div>
</div>
</header>

Comment: .banner-inner{
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.centered{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make a few changes to your style to make it responsive. 
Your Centered class has a margin left and right set to auto to center it horizontally. We made margin top a % so it will decrease as the image does.
We also used display flex to center everything. and set a font which will decrease via media queries.  I also added a width of 100% to the image and an auto height.

The CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1000px){.centered{font-size:12pt!important;}}
@media only screen and (max-width:800px){.centered{font-size:11pt!important;}}
@media only screen and (max-width:600px){.centered{font-size:10pt!important;}}
@media only screen and (max-width:400px){.centered{font-size:9pt!important;}}
@media only screen and (max-width:200px){.centered{font-size:8pt!important;}}
.banner-inner{ 
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute; 
text-align: center; 
color: white; 
} 
.centered{ 
position: absolute; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
width:100%;
height:auto;
margin-top:20%;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align:center;
font-size:12pt;
}
.img{
width:100%;
height:auto;
float:left;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="banner-inner"> 
<img class="img" alt="" src="img/Website PC.png"> 
<div class="centered"><a href="courses.html">Start Learning</a></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: The "Start Learning" link still does not shrink when the image shrinks as I decrease the browser width. The link also still does not stay centered in the image when I decrease the browser width.

Comment: Basically what I am wanting is for the "Start Learning" link to always be in the center of the image no matter the screen size. If I am on a desktop computer I want the link centered in the image, if I am on a mobile device, I still want the link to show in the middle of the image.

Comment: This should do it. I have updated my answer to make it responsive.

Comment: Thank you so much, this did fix my problem Jonny

Comment: No problem Glad to Help Anytime

Comment: By chance is there a way to make the font size larger when I am on desktop for the "start learning" link? it just seems a bit smaller than what i wanted when viewing on desktop

Comment: Yes just set the font size in the centered class and go up to your media queries start at the top and adjust the size according to the resolution size.

Answer (score 1):

use vw(% of the viewport width) for your font size it will scale the size of your font and I set some css for your code that makes your button responsive and centered even if you resize your browser width.

```css
  .banner-inner
  { 
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      position:relative; 
      text-align: center; 
  } 
  .centered
  { 
      position: absolute; 
      margin: 0 auto;
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
      display: block;
      text-align:center;
      font-size:6vw;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  .centered a
  {
   margin: 0 auto;
   color: #000;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 20px;
  }
  .img
  {
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   object-fit: cover;
  }
```

```html
<div class="banner-inner"> 
    <img class="img" alt="" src="https://img00.deviantart.net/080b/i/2014/360/d/3/texture_13_by_sirius_sdz-d19qqe1.jpg"> 
    <div class="centered"><a href="courses.html">Start Learning</a></div> 
</div>
```